# Problems redirecting with mod rewrite in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have problems with redirecting with htaccess. We have a new website and we want don’t want to use extensions in the url’s anymore. We have been using .php and .html extensions. I also want to redirect all the pages to the version with www. in front. We are also using https for the first time, so everything should also be redirected to https://www. Of course everything with 301 redirects for SEO. A few old files have underscores in the filename, I want to convert them to a dash too. I am now using this hatches, but it’s not working correct.

```
# activeer rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# bepaal je rootdirectory (set root)
RewriteBase /

# verwijder de .php extensie (remove .php)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# verwijder de .html extensie (remove .html)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]

# verwijder index (delete index)
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# verwijder de trailing slash als het geen map is (remove trailingtrash)
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
# RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# verzoek om te verwijzen naar php bestand (request php-file)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

# verzoek om te verwijzen naar html bestand (request php-file)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]

# underscores omzetten in streepjes (convert underscores to dashes)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)_(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*)/ http://www.previewwebsite.nl$1-$2/ [R=301]

# zonder www verwijzen naar www (redirect to www. instead of non-www)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^previewwebsite\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.previewwebsite.nl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can test it on http://www.previewwebsite.nl/kasteel_trouwen.php. I have no SSL set on this domain, it’s for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `L` flags in your redirects, otherwise the rules after them will get applied. Also, make sure all your redirects are at the top:

```
# activeer rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# bepaal je rootdirectory (set root)
RewriteBase /

# underscores omzetten in streepjes (convert underscores to dashes)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)_(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*)/ https://www.previewwebsite.nl$1-$2/ [L,R=301]

# zonder www verwijzen naar www (redirect to www. instead of non-www)
# also redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^previewwebsite\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.previewwebsite.nl/$1 [L,R=301]

# verwijder de .php extensie (remove .php)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301]

# verwijder de .html extensie (remove .html)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [L,R=301]

# verwijder index (delete index)
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# verwijder de trailing slash als het geen map is (remove trailingtrash)
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
# RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [L,R=301]

# verzoek om te verwijzen naar php bestand (request php-file)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

# verzoek om te verwijzen naar html bestand (request php-file)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately it is not working in all situations. This is not working: http://previewwebsite.nl/faciliteiten.php > http://www.previewwebsite.nl/http://previewwebsite.nl/www/htdocs/testssit/faciliteiten. And this not too: http://www.previewwebsite.nl/kasteel_trouwen.php > http://www.previewwebsite.nlhttp://www.previewwebsite.nl/www/htdocs/testssit/kasteel-trouwen. Hope you can help...